# Couldn't load image when using merge-images

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using [merge-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-images) library to merge images, but it shows below error

```
Couldn't load image
```

The mergeImg method:

```
    mergeImg() {
      mergeImages([
        "@/assets/body.png",
        "@/assets/eyes.png",
        "@/assets/logo.png",
      ]).then((b64) => {
        console.log(b64);
        document.querySelector("img").src = b64;
      });
    },
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hill-hop84?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: That errormessage is generated [here](https://github.com/lukechilds/merge-images/blob/master/src/index.js#L29). It seems your image cant be loaded properly. Maybe the entered paths arent correct (or merge-images cant resolve the "@").